# A real valued function to be studied please!

Tags: functions

How can I know exactly the domain of definition, and study the monotonicity of 
$$f(x)=x^{0.5}-(x+\ln x)^{0.5}{}{}{}$$
Where I don't know exactly the boundary of the domain, i.e surely
greater than zero and between $0.5$ and $0.6$!

Comment: This question is unreadable!

Comment: To check monotonicity take the derivative of the function and check if it is always the same sign. For the domain ask yourself when the function is infinite and when you take the square root of a negative number.

Comment: Ik all the ways to obtain the domain and the monotonicity but im not able to obtain the exact domain of this function, can anyone help

Comment: @mhamad Be more specific. What exactly is causing difficulties?

Comment: For example, x+ln x shall be greater than zero i.e lnx>-x, can i know the set of points that verifies this?

Comment: Ok, sorry, now I got your question. The answer contains $W$-Lambert function and is $e^{-W(1)}$ (about $0.56$). You may see the solution here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%2B+ln%28x%29+%3D+0 and read more about Lambert function here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Thankyou very much, this was an exam question where i couldnt find the exact domain! So i gave its approximation! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Domain consist of $\mathbb R$ excluding such $x$ for which nested functions are not defined.
Here you have $\sqrt{x}$, $\ln x$ and $\sqrt{x + \ln x}$ - functions with domain less than $\mathbb R$. Intersection of all of these domains will give you $\mathscr D(f)$. 
Monotonuosity can be studied by taking a derivative and solving the inequality $f'(x) > 0$.